# How to conditionally install a Python dependency only if Apple Silicon Rosetta 2 is being used?

Tags: python, macos, pip

I want to pip install a certain package when using Apple Silicon + Rosetta 2 and another package otherwise. What's the best way to do this?

One approach I thought of is this. Pip supports [environment markers](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0508/#environment-markers) that let you conditionally install dependencies like so.

```
atomac==1.1.0; sys_platform == 'darwin'
```

Anyone know if it’s possible and how to use `sysctl` as an environment marker? My use case is that `sysctl -in sysctl.proc_translated` returns 1 on Apple Silicon + Rosetta 2 and 0 otherwise. On other platforms like Ubuntu, sysctl might not be available as a command.

Another approach is to have two different requirements.txt files and run a script that selects the appropriate one based on return value of `sysctl -in sysctl.proc_translated`.